# Support of form and embedded varieties

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I need help with some inclusions.
Let $i: S \rightarrow M$ be an embedding between two  oriented varieties of dimension k and n respectively. Assume that the $i(S)$ is closed and that $\omega\in \Omega_c^k(M)$. So, I wrote (a looong time ago) $\text{supp} (i^*\omega)\subset i^{-1}(\text{supp}\omega)$, and here there is the first problem because I do not see the inclusion .
And then I wrote $i^{-1} (\text{supp}\omega) \cap S \subset \text{supp}\omega$. I do not understand. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in S$ such that $i^* \omega$ does not vanish at $x$. So there exists $u_1, \dots, u_k \in T_x S$ such that $(i^*\omega)_x(u_1, \dots u_k) \neq 0$ i.e. $\omega_{i(x)}(i_* u_1, \dots , i_* u_k) \neq 0$. This shows that $\omega$ does not vanish at $i(x)$. It follows that $\mathrm{supp}(i^*\omega) \subset i^{-1}(\mathrm{supp}\, \omega)$.

The second thing you wrote only makes sense if $i$ is an actual inclusion. And then it does not say much because in that case, $i^{-1}(\mathrm{supp}\, \omega) = (\mathrm{supp}\, \omega) \cap S$.